# ngrx effects calls http several times

Tags: angular, rest, ionic-framework, redux, ngrx

I am using the latest versions of ngrx (4.1.1) and angular 4.4.4 and can't find the problem here and could need some help.

I am using an effect which calls the this.apiProvider.getLogisticsFolder() and works with the http response. As soon as my reducer returns the new state and everything is working as expected, my rest service is called a second time or even several times (the action/effect is only triggered once and so is the rest call getLogisticsFolder()).

What am I missing here?

```
@Effect()
syncFolders$ = this.actions$
    .ofType<LogisticsFolderActions.SyncFolders>(LogisticsFolderActions.SYNC_FOLDERS)
    .mergeMap(() => this.apiProvider.getLogisticsFolder()
        .withLatestFrom(this._store.select(state => state.logisticsFolders), this._store.select(state => state.settings))
        .map(([cloudLogisticsFolder, localLogisticsFolderState, settingsState]) =>
        {
            let tempLocalLogisticsFolder = localLogisticsFolderState.find(localLogisticsFolderState => localLogisticsFolderState.tenant === settingsState.baseURL);
            if (tempLocalLogisticsFolder)
            {
                //now check if the folder structure has been added, deleted or changed
                let updatedFolders = this.logisticsFolderProvider.checkAndProceedLogisticsFolderUpdate(cloudLogisticsFolder, tempLocalLogisticsFolder.logisticsFolders)
                this.logisticsFolderProvider.checkAndProceedTasksUpdate(cloudLogisticsFolder, updatedFolders)

                return new LogisticsFolderActions.SyncSuccess;
            } else
            {
                let logisticsFolderState = <LogisticsFolder.State>{};
                logisticsFolderState.tenant = settingsState.baseURL;
                logisticsFolderState.logisticsFolders = cloudLogisticsFolder;
                return new LogisticsFolderActions.SyncSuccess({ logisticsFolder: logisticsFolderState });
            }
        })
        .catch((error) =>
        {
            this._store.dispatch(new AppActions.UnexpectedError(error.json().message));
            return Observable.of(new LogisticsFolderActions.SyncFailed)
        })
    );
```

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 2):

fixed...

I subscribed to the token which is assigned to this.token$ and as the state was updated a new value was executed and so we had several requests.

```
private oAuthRequest(options): Observable<any>
    {
        return this.token$.flatMap(token =>
        {
            options.headers = new Headers();
            options.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            options.headers.append('Authorization', token);

            if (options.body && typeof options.body !== 'string')
            {
                options.body = JSON.stringify(options.body);
            }

            return this.http
                .request(new Request(options))
                .map((res: Response) =>
                {
                    if (res.text)
                    {
                        return res.json();
                    }
                    return res
                });
        }).take(1);

    }
```